# Como gerar automaticamente os campos no Firebase CloudFirestorage

Tags: banco-de-dados, ionic, firebase

Estou usando banco de dados do Firebase 'CloudFirestore', gostaria de saber se é possível salvar os campos automaticamente, para quando for adicionar qualquer item novo, não precisar escrever o nome de cada campo e o valor.
Se não for possível, o que você me indica para adicionar qualquer dado novo? Acredito que dê para eu usar as mesmas credenciais em algum outro aplicativo apenas para adicionar novos dados, mas estou na dúvida. [image: Firebase CloudFirestore]

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta, pode dar algum exemplo?